# Editing a route in Bing Maps Windows Phone 7 : In-App or BingMapsDirectionsTask

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I want to edit the routes of a map in Windows Phone 7.1.

Current functionality: Custom bing maps control asking for two points and route is drawn using these methods specified in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681887.aspx

Trying to mimic these functionalities from BingMaps web interface.

1. Route based on start and end 
   [image: Route based on start and end]
2. Start of change of route
   [image: Start of change of route]

3.Final route after the edit 
 [image]

Current functionality in app:

GestureListener attached to added map layer  containing  route line -->(To listen to Drag Start , DragCompleted)
Map Pan event  --> to disable the map zoom effect if map layer is dragged

Trying to mimic the equivalent effect on dragging and changing a route while in Bing Maps, was able to update the layer.

Issues:
Precise control on map layer drag achieved at high zoom levels only.

In effect when trying to mimic the bingMaps web control features in Metro, the polished feel in UI is lost.

So thinking of alternate ways like :-

Is  this feature possible via  BingMapsDirectionsTask  to get a callback back to the application after opening bingMaps?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're doing and the conditions under which it does and doesn't work?

Comment: But how are you currenlty trying to do it? How many layers are you using? What is on each layer? What happens at the zoom levels where it doesn't work?

Comment: Currently trying with one layer containing the routeLine and when the user drags the line,that layer is redrawn with the new point. At smaller zoom levels , the dragging of map layer is hit and miss. I tried increasing the routeLine width and it started working, because as the area of line is high, we can drag it precisely. I was trying for a smooth solution though.

Comment: I searched in apps and most of the map editing features are provided on web page interface for app support than in mobile app. Is it because of the usability confusions?

Comment: So is your question: how to accurately move a location when zoomed out a long way?

Comment: @MattLacey yes, and is there any best practice regarding using maps in  apps, that is why i asked about bingmapsdirectiontask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's very little that's configurable in the BingMapsTask or the BingMapsDirectionsTask. They're also launchers and not choosers and so don't return anything after you return from them to your app.

What you're trying to do is almost a contradiction. You're trying to make a small adjustment from a great distance.
I wonder if there's any value in trying to do this. The value of being able to zoom in is to be able to see the detail and accuracy you're after.

It's almost like asking how to paint in fine detail while holding the end of a long brush. You just wouldn't. You'd use an appropriate tool for the job and use it in the way it's intended and suited to the task "in hand".

Obviously I haven't seen the app you're trying to build and how you expect user to interact with it.
It does raise a bunch of alarm bells for me though as you're trying to perform a fine grained interaction with an inaccurate input device-a finger.
I also expect that if there really is value in providing such functionality on a small screen, mobile device then there's likely to be a learning curve for users. I'd encourage you to test with real users early to see how they can use the device and how to tune the experience so that users can get the results and behaviour they want as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

No war intended, If you are traveling from Oxford to Wolverhampton, you might take the clockwise or anticlockwise route around Birmingham M40, M42, M5 or the clockwise one M40, M42, M6 Aylesbury to Dover, which way around the M25? Large scale choice of routes. The users are likely to be familiar (first) with Google Maps or Bing Maps, both of which provide this functionality. That is the direction we are coming from. If you move you finger on a part of the map where there isnt a route, then the map pans. If your finger is "over" a route, then the route moves, irrespective of map scale.

[image: route around birmingham]